# Calling javascript function from objectiveC

Tags: iphone

I have a function/method in .html file and I need to call that function from objective C code. I have a page with UIWebView and we need to call and pass few parameters to javascript function in .html file. Please let me know if anybody has any answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have a function like below in Javascript

```
function getTheName(id)
{
//Some stuff
return name;
}
```

You can call , pass parameters and get back a value from it like below

```
NSString *ID = @"THE_ID";
NSString *theJSMethod = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"getTheName('%@')", ID ];
NSString *returnedValueFromJSMethod = [yourWebViewInstance stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:theJSMethod];
```