# JavaScript method is not getting called on web view in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an HTML file and JS file in my app. When the web view is loaded I am loading my html file which contains the reference to JavaScript file. I have added the JavaScript file in to my bundle resource for compile sources and in the web view did finish load I am calling a JavaScript function which increases the font size of HTML content but the JavaScript method is not getting called.

This is my code:

```
NSString *readerstring = @"document.getElementById('reader')";
      [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"adjustFontSize('%@'.contentDocument, '4.0')",readerstring]];
```

Comment: There is no need to do `[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:]` you can just do `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the font size of `UIWebView` like this,

```
int fontSize = 20;
NSString *String = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'", fontSize];
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

or

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.style.fontSize = '8px'"];
```

Hope it will helps you...

Comment: yes i know this but how to call .js file function in my webview

Comment: adjustFontSize() is a method in my js file

Comment: i am not much familier with js, please refer the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334047/how-to-call-javascript-function-in-objective-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893852/calling-javascript-function-from-objectivec

Comment: refer this sample code for bridging between js and obj-c https://github.com/meadlai/MDCommonWebView

Comment: are you calling the js funtion after web view finished its loading?

Comment: @Ajithmn89 yes i am calling the js function in webviewdidfinish load method

Comment: before calling the function u need to evaluate your js file with the webview.

Answer (score 0):

Call the JS function after web view finished its loading.

And if you are using any of jQuery functions don forget to add jquery.js and evaluate it.

```
    -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

    NSMutableString  *jsStr  =[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jquery.min" ofType:@"js"]] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsStr];
jsStr  =[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourown" ofType:@"js"]] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsStr];
//evalute your js file before calling its function 
[WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myFunctionToChangethefontSize();"];

 //change font size directly
    [WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('#divContent').css('font-size', '18px');"];

    }
```

Important:

Check whether the JS file in compile resource bundle then you have to remove it from there and add it in copy Bundle Resource.

Comment: did you evaluated your js file before calling your js function?

Comment: can i send u my html and js file

Comment: put alert(); inside that js function call at the beginning and at the end to check whether its called or not.

Comment: check whether the js file in compile resource bundle then you have to remove it from there and add it in copy Bundle Resourse

Comment: i have added alert in the js file but it not getting called

Comment: check whether the js file in compile resource bundle then you have to remove it from there and add it in copy Bundle Resourse

Comment: js file is in copy bundle resource

Comment: if it is in  compile resource bundle remove it from there